# How to move to behind the Remarks for column EDIT and DELETE in asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am using the data binding to get the data from a SQL Server database. After the last column (`Remarks`), I want the `EDIT` and `DELETE` buttons to look like this (see screenshot).

How can I move the column for the user to click on the edit and delete button?

I need help for this. Thank you.

The output design that I want:

[image: Image 1]

The output that I to add the EDIT & DELETE

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Plor.png]

The source code that will get the data from SQL Server using Entity Framework:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="panel panel-col-sm-8" id="DisplayData" style="border-color:steelblue; width: auto;">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:royalblue; font-weight: bold;">Data Display</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdRDaily" runat="server" Visible="false" Width="356px" CssClass="table table-bordered" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true"  />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            &nbsp;
            <p id="demo"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code behind on how I get the data:

```
private void GetDailySummary()
{
    grdRDaily.Visible = true;

    // get headcount summary
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlCommand sqlComm;

        sqlComm = new SqlCommand("EXEC psp_RPTDaily " + " @DATA = '" + dataReport.SelectedValue.ToString() + "', @FROMDATE = '" + txtStartDate.Text + "',  @TODATE = '" + txtEndDate.Text + "'", conn);

        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

        da.Fill(ds);

        grdRDaily.DataSourceID = null;
        grdRDaily.DataSource = ds;
        grdRDaily.DataBind();

        grdRDaily.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the [GridView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview) documentation? Have you tried using [TemplateField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield)s?

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning. Yes, I have reading the documentation and I have try every ways and it doesn't work as what I want. 
I use AutoGenerateColumns = "false" and the data doesn't show but just show my data.